# What methods should save/load a game state

Tags: android, state, libgdx, savegame

There are a lot of articles about how to save a state of a game and they are pretty good. But I have one conceptual misunderstanding where should I save the state?

My game has number of screens and pair of them are *MainMenuScreen* and *MainSceneScreen* these are inherited from *Screen* class. *MainMenuScreen* is shown at start of the game the *MainSceneScreen* little later.

What is the problem? I navigated to *MainSceneScreen*, forced Android to stop the application (I change a language settings on the device to achieve it, please let me know if I'm wrong). After that I select the application again and I can see *MainMenuScreen* is shown. But I want *MainSceneScreen* to be shown.

I suppose I should override resume method. But what class I should override? I have class *PsGame* that extends *Game* class of libgdx. I put breakpoints to its resume method and  it turned out that method was not called. I investigated the problem and I've found little strange code in *onResume* method of  *AndroidApplication* class of libgdx:

```
    if (!firstResume)
        graphics.resume();
    else
        firstResume = false;
```

My debugger said *firstResume* was true and didn't go to *graphics.resume()*line.

Sorry for a lot of words but could you answer following question:

1. What did I do wrong?
2. What methods should I override?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I overrid resume() in the class tha extends Game in libgdx, and when i press the home button and enter the app again it executes and it enters that method

Comment: @Rudy_TM You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I override resume() in the class tha extends Game in libgdx, and when i press the home button and enter the app again it executes and it enters that method.